# Decomposing a matrix into elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading Milnor's Introduction to Algebraic K theory and come across the following claim on page 25: $\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & A^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix}$ could be decomposed as a product of elementary matrices following from proof of 2.5, which contains an observation looking like $$ \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
0 & A^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
I & A \\
0 & I 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
-A^{-1} & I 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
I & A \\
0 & I 
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$ Here an elementary matrix is a matrix that coincides with the identity except for a single off-diagonal entry. Any ideas on how to decompose such matrices into product of elementary matrices?

Comment: Your definition of "elementary matrix" seems to be different from [the usual one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

Comment: Yes I know, but that's the definition that Milnor used. So, that's what I want to use. Also, I secretly suspect that these two definitions are perhaps the same?

Comment: You need to deal with "row switching matrices", i.e. something like $\begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\1& 0\end{bmatrix}$. This adds some complication. Here the determinant is $1$ so I guess you are right.

Comment: @WhatsUp: Normally you also need elementary matrices corresponding to multiplying a row by a number $\alpha\ne 0$. The property $det=1$ does not eliminate the issue. Say, diag$(1,2,1/2)$. Fortunately in this case one does not need these elementary matrices and the switch matrices, as I explained in my answer .

Comment: I'd like to see a clearer problem setup.  What are the "matrices" shown in the body of your Question?  Are these $2\times 2$ matrices or block matrices of (say) size $2n\times 2n$?  Some housekeeping edit of that kind would improve the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of elementary matrix is slightly different: for every elementary row transformation $\rho$ the elementary matrix $E(\rho)$ is the matrix obtained from the identity matrix $I$ by applying $\rho$. Milnor's elementary matrices correspond to $\rho$'s which add one row multiplied by a number to another row. If $\rho_1,..., \rho_m$ are elementary row transformations needed to transform $B$ to $I$ then $E(\rho_m^{-1})\cdot ...\cdot E(\rho_1^{-1})$ is a product of elementary matrices that is equal to $B$.

In your product of four matrixes
$$\begin{bmatrix}
I & A \\
0 & I 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
-A^{-1} & I 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
I & A \\
0 & I 
\end{bmatrix}\cdot  \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -I \\
I & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the first three matrices require only Milnor's elementary matrices to reduce them to the identity matrix.

The fourth matrix also only needs these row transformations: First add rows $n+1$,...,$2n$ to rows $1,...,n$ respectively. Then subtract rows $1,...,n$ from rows $n+1,...,2n$.

Thus each of the four matrices is a product of "Milnor" elementary matrices and you are done.

Comment: As for the discussion in the coment section of my question, do you happen to know if elementary matrices corresponding to adding multiple of one row to another row generate the two other kinds of elementary matrices? Or, worded in another way, are these three types of elementary matrices independent of each other?

Comment: They don't generate the switch because the add elementary matrices have det $=1$ and switch matrices have det $-1$. Similarly "multiply row" matrices have non-$1$ determinants usually so they are not generated by the add transformations. The switch transformation is a composition of add transformations and "multiply row by $-1$" transformation.
To switch row $i$ and row $j$: add row $j$ to row $i$, subtract   row $i$ from row $j$, multiply row $j$ by $-1$, subtract row $j$ from row $i$.

Comment: Splendid! Thank you for helping!